# Failure to cross-compile Rust programs on Arch Linux

Tags: rust, embedded-linux, cross-compiling, arm64, archlinux

```
$ cargo build --target aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu --release
   Compiling libc v0.2.148
   Compiling pkg-config v0.3.27
   Compiling bitflags v1.3.2
   Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
   Compiling scopeguard v1.2.0
   Compiling bitflags v2.0.2
   Compiling libudev-sys v0.1.4
error: failed to run custom build command for `libudev-sys v0.1.4`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/user/embedded/target/release/build/libudev-sys-3f0e31dcfa4672e0/build-script-build` (exit status: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=LIBUDEV_NO_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: "pkg-config has not been configured to support cross-compilation.\n\nInstall a sysroot for the target platform and configure it via\nPKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR and PKG_CONFIG_PATH, or install a\ncross-compiling wrapper for pkg-config and set it via\nPKG_CONFIG environment variable."', /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/libudev-sys-0.1.4/build.rs:38:41
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

`libudev` and `systemd-libs` are installed.

```
$ pacman -Qs libudev
local/lib32-libgudev 238-1
    GObject bindings for libudev
local/lib32-systemd 254.4-1
    system and service manager (32-bit)
local/libgudev 238-1
    GObject bindings for libudev
local/systemd-libs 254.4-1
    systemd client libraries
```

Edit Cargo.toml to

```
serialport = {version = "4.2.2", default-features = false}
```

Get a new error

```
$ RUST_BACKTRACE=1 cargo build --target aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu --release
   Compiling libc v0.2.148
   Compiling bitflags v1.3.2
   Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
   Compiling scopeguard v1.2.0
   Compiling bitflags v2.0.2
   Compiling nix v0.26.4
   Compiling serialport v4.2.2
   Compiling embedded v0.1.0 (/home/user/embedded)
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin:/home/user/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/cuda/bin:/opt/cuda/nsight_compute:/opt/cuda/nsight_systems/bin:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/usr/lib/rustup/bin" VSLANG="1033" "cc" "/tmp/rustcin6FNC/symbols.o" "/home/user/embedded/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/embedded-391f84b2cc73fe7b.embedded.dcf744dab38932c5-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "/home/user/embedded/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/embedded-391f84b2cc73fe7b.3b4zw2avb9b1d901.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "/home/user/embedded/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps" "-L" "/home/user/embedded/target/release/deps" "-L" "/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-cca993492431c26c.rlib" "/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-767683484988fddb.rlib" "/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libobject-33d8ca36e0751c49.rlib" "/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libmemchr-feb6369d9fb8ea6a.rlib" "/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libaddr2line-da5e802c6b261da9.rlib" "/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libgimli-c11c22644b73fbb3.rlib" "/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_demangle-b538894d8056db90.rlib" "/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd_detect-5f75957d64265585.rlib" "/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libhashbrown-eb377e4796f89c63.rlib" "/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-7959bd6dc5a6dc9b.rlib" "/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libminiz_oxide-27e9cf0ad28ebc46.rlib" "/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libadler-9a4d8927e95998a8.rlib" "/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunwind-7ce72c5f7491b638.rlib" "/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcfg_if-88468c0375a0c64b.rlib" "/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-ceea9f1fc4b03431.rlib" "/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-96085dbefe195fa8.rlib" "/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-a8add003da8dc54d.rlib" "/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-082d5e9d53946848.rlib" "/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-21239b3d9ec3b48b.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lgcc_s" "-lutil" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lm" "-ldl" "-lc" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-Wl,-z,noexecstack" "-L" "/home/user/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-o" "/home/user/embedded/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/embedded-391f84b2cc73fe7b" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-z,relro,-z,now" "-Wl,-O1" "-nodefaultlibs"
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/embedded/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/embedded-391f84b2cc73fe7b.embedded.dcf744dab38932c5-cgu.0.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/embedded/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/embedded-391f84b2cc73fe7b.embedded.dcf744dab38932c5-cgu.0.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/embedded/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/embedded-391f84b2cc73fe7b.embedded.dcf744dab38932c5-cgu.0.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/embedded/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/embedded-391f84b2cc73fe7b.embedded.dcf744dab38932c5-cgu.0.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/embedded/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/embedded-391f84b2cc73fe7b.embedded.dcf744dab38932c5-cgu.0.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/embedded/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/embedded-391f84b2cc73fe7b.embedded.dcf744dab38932c5-cgu.0.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/embedded/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/embedded-391f84b2cc73fe7b.embedded.dcf744dab38932c5-cgu.0.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/embedded/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/embedded-391f84b2cc73fe7b.embedded.dcf744dab38932c5-cgu.0.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/embedded/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/embedded-391f84b2cc73fe7b.embedded.dcf744dab38932c5-cgu.0.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/embedded/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/embedded-391f84b2cc73fe7b.embedded.dcf744dab38932c5-cgu.0.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/embedded/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/embedded-391f84b2cc73fe7b.embedded.dcf744dab38932c5-cgu.0.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/embedded/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/embedded-391f84b2cc73fe7b.embedded.dcf744dab38932c5-cgu.0.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/embedded/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/embedded-391f84b2cc73fe7b.embedded.dcf744dab38932c5-cgu.0.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/embedded/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/embedded-391f84b2cc73fe7b.embedded.dcf744dab38932c5-cgu.0.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/embedded/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/embedded-391f84b2cc73fe7b.embedded.dcf744dab38932c5-cgu.0.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/embedded/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/embedded-391f84b2cc73fe7b.embedded.dcf744dab38932c5-cgu.0.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/embedded/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/embedded-391f84b2cc73fe7b.embedded.dcf744dab38932c5-cgu.0.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/embedded/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/embedded-391f84b2cc73fe7b.embedded.dcf744dab38932c5-cgu.0.rcgu.o: Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 183)
          /usr/bin/ld: /home/user/embedded/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/embedded-391f84b2cc73fe7b.embedded.dcf744dab38932c5-cgu.0.rcgu.o: error adding symbols: file in wrong format
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          

error: could not compile `embedded` (bin "embedded") due to previous error
```

But, Cross-compiling Windows programs is normal （x86_64-pc-windows-gnu）

Comment: *"pkg-config has not been configured to support cross-compilation"*

Comment: Also when you say `libudev` and `systemd-libs` are installed, are they installed _for the target system_? I.e. are the AArch64 versions installed?

Comment: I can't find libudev and systemd-libs for Aarch64 in the Arch Linux repositories.

Comment: > "pkg-config has not been configured to support cross-compilation"
How to do it ?

Comment: Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66272299/cross-compiling-rusts-serialport-crate and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68871193/pkg-config-error-during-rust-cross-compilation

Comment: Addendum: Cross-compiling Windows programs is normal （x86_64-pc-windows-gnu）

Comment: You shouldn't add extra info into comments, [edit] your question instead.

Comment: When cross-compiling, you need to: 1. Get a toolchain and root filesystem for your target system (e.g. install the `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc` package), 2. [Tell Rust to use this toolchain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39320804/5397009), and 3. Install the dependencies in the target root filesystem (you probably won't find pre-made packages for that, so you will need to do it by hand).